# How to update values in ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template">
    <span class="count-container">
        <span >{{count}}</span>
    </span>
</script>
```

and I am including this multiple times with different `ng-init` like this

```
<span ng-include="'template'" ng-init="count=$ctrl.getTotalCount()"></span>

<span ng-include="'template'" ng-init="count=$ctrl.tabs[0].errorCount"></span>
```

this works fine on the very first load, but when the values are updated in the component, those are not reflected where the template is loaded. I guess it's due to how the `ng-init` works since it's everything fine on the 1st load.

So what should be used so that the values are updated in the template?

Comment: Where is `count` being defined? Is it within or outside the loop of the template?

Comment: count is in template.
how do i update it from controller, can you please give an example.
how can i use ngModel for it?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I'm not sure if setting an `ng-model` to `span` would work.

Comment: @AmarKoli It will not be clear what is wrong until you show the controller code.

Comment: I don't think you need to even use `ng-init` with `ng-template`. That should be done with your `ng-controller`.

Comment: the controller code is very big, its inside a component. $ctrl.getTotalCount() is function which get the count. and $ctrl.tabs[0].errorCount is a separate variable which is updated in different function in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$watch`:

```
ng-init="$watch('count=$ctrl.tabs[0].errorCount')"
```

This is just an inline solution. However, you should use `scope.$watch()`.

Comment: let me try this